# Powershell Script error logging function doesn't older ps compatibilty and exitcoding

Tags: function, powershell, logging, error-logging

Ok. So I will begin at the beginning.

I have a function that I created to create log files that are easily read and understood that provide context and error details for when something goes wrong.

The function itself looks like this:

```
#error logging
function log ([string[]] $error)
 <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Provides a means of error logging step by step script processes.
  .DESCRIPTION
  This can be used to generate log entries into a log file based on success and failure of a script. Also provides a means of outputting script errors.
  .EXAMPLE
  Log("<Message>")
  Log($error)
  #>
{
    if (!(Test-Path "C:\SCCMPS\Logs\"))
        {New-Item "C:\SCCMPS\Logs\" -ItemType Dir}

    if ($error[0].length -eq 0 -and $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
        { (Get-Date).ToString() + " - Command Completed Successfully" >> $logname }
    else
    {
        if($error[0].length -ne 0)
            { (Get-Date).ToString() + " - " + $error >> $logname }
    }
    $global:error.clear()
}
$logname = "C:\SCCMPS\Logs\$program.log"
$logheader = "##### At " + (Get-Date).ToString() + ", the installation for $program version $curver was started under the user " + [environment]::userdomainname + "\" + [environment]::username.ToString() + " #####"
$logheader >> $logname
Log("Running location is $tempdir")
```

This is used in a script as such...

```
############## Variable Declaration ##############
$program = ".Net 3.5"
$curver = "3.5"
$tempdir = Get-Location
$tempdir = $tempdir.tostring()

#Include IT Powershell Functions
. "\\fileserver\share$\errorlogging.ps1"

############## Installation ##############
Log("Looking for $program")
if(!(Test-Key "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" "Install")) 
    {
    Log("$program not found, installing.")
    Start-Process DISM.exe -ArgumentList "/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:$tempdir\sxs" -PassThru -Wait
    Log($error[0])
    } ELSE { Log("$program already installed, skipping.") }

############## END ##############
Log("=================== END OF LOG ===================")
```

I have two problems.  First, I would like to figure out a way to make the Log($error) to display the exitcode for the process that it just checked for errors as well as displaying the "Command Completed Successfully" or "$error[0]" text.

The second problem, Windows 7 systems in my organization are running Powershell Version 2.  I am not going to be able to deploy Windows Management Framework 5.0 (for reasons I won't get into) so I would like to make this error logging work properly on Powershell 2.0.  Currently that version doesn't properly evaluate $error.length and therefore it will not work for showing if something erred out.

All suggestions/changes are welcomed and appreciated.  I am self-taught and still very much learning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I figure it can't hurt. So in my opinion and experience the best way to handle PowerShell script errors would be to use a [Try/Catch block](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx).

Run your script with different scenarios to generate different error messages for different events (Example, if you write a script that installs software from a network drive, disconnect from the network and run the script, this will generate a powershell error., etc...). After receiving each error for each scenario you would want to execute the following to get the Powershell Error Name:

```
$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName
```

Once you get the PowerShell name for the exception thrown you can use it in a [Try/Catch block](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) like:

```
Try 
{
    Write-Output "Installing Package..."

    #Adding "-ErrorAction Stop" to end of command will tell it stop action. Here is where catch block will take over
    Install-Package -Name Fake -ErrorAction Stop 
}

Catch [System.Exception] #Put error you got from "$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName" in brackets
{
    Write-Host "ERROR: The Package Fake, Does Not Exist. Contact Your Administrator" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Running the example above without error handling would normally show:

```
    Installing Package...
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Fake'.
At line:4 char:13
+             Install-Package -Name Fake
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

With [Try/Catch block](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) error handling the following is shown instead:

```
    Installing Package...
ERROR: The Package Fake, Does Not Exist. Contact Your Administrator
```

Lastly, for the catch block, if no brackets are specified all errors will be caught and display same text. If you want to handle multiple errors, you would add additional catch blocks for each error you want to handle. You can also mix the two so you could handle specific errors and then use the catch all to catch any errors you haven't specifically handled. See Examples:

```
            #Catch all error handling
        Catch
        {
            Write-Output "No Error was Specified on catch block. So this Message will be show regardless of what error occurs!"
        }

        #Multiple Error Handling
        Catch [Error1]
        {
            Write-Output "Some error message here"
        }

        Catch [Error2]
        {
            Write-Output "Next error here"
        }
```

Again my apologies if this isn't what you were looking for, I really hope this help you in some way.

Comment: It is handy and I use try-catch blocks for other things but haven't used it for error logging.